# CSS: Showing Hidden Element with "position: fixed" Disturbs User's Y-Scroll Position

Tags: css, position

I have some code which generates a dialog box.  It can be a confirmation, acknowledgement, etc.

The code is called on clicking some element.  For example, if I click the trash icon, I cause a "delete" confirmation dialog to be created and rendered.

Notice that I insert the dialog as the first element in the `<body>`.  This works well, except for forms where there has been some Y-scrolling.  When the page has been scrolled, if I display the dialog, the page always auto-scrolls back to the top before displaying the dialog.

I thought `position: fixed` should prevent changes to the scroll position by always making the element relative to the viewport, but it doesn't.

Here is where the dynamic dialog `<div>` is created:

```
function CustomDialog(title, body, buttons){

  let bodyElement = document.querySelector("body");

  let dynamicShadowElement = document.createElement("div");
  dynamicShadowElement.id = "dialog-shadow";
  bodyElement.insertBefore(dynamicShadowElement, bodyElement.childNodes[0]);

  let dynamicOverlayElement = document.createElement("div");
  dynamicOverlayElement.id = "dialog-overlay";
  bodyElement.insertBefore(dynamicOverlayElement, dynamicShadowElement);

  let dynamicInnerHTML = "<div id='dialog-box'><div id='dialog-box-header'></div>";
  dynamicInnerHTML += "<div id='dialog-box-body'></div><div id='dialog-box-footer'></div></div>";

  dynamicShadowElement.innerHTML = dynamicInnerHTML;

  let dialogOverlay = document.getElementById("dialog-overlay");
  let dialogShadow = document.getElementById("dialog-shadow");
  let dialogBox = document.getElementById('dialog-box');
  let dialogBoxHeader = document.getElementById('dialog-box-header');
  let dialogBoxBody = document.getElementById('dialog-box-body');
  let dialogBoxFooter = document.getElementById('dialog-box-footer');

  dialogOverlay.style.display = "block";
  dialogShadow.style.display = "block";
  dialogBox.style.display = "block";
  dialogBoxHeader.innerHTML = title;
  dialogBoxBody.innerHTML = body;

  if (!buttons) {
    // Create a default button to close the dialog.

    buttons = [{
        onclick: () => { closeDialog(); },
        text: "Got it!",
        class: "btn-primary"
    }];
  }

  buttons.forEach( (button) => {
    let dynamicButtonElement = document.createElement("button");

    and so on...
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#dialog-overlay{
  background: #FFF;
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: .6;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
#dialog-shadow{
  display: none;
  background: LightGray;
  border-radius: 7px;
  left: 10%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 150px;
  width: 80%;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

How can I make my dialog appear without disturbing the current scroll position of the page?

Comment: Please read "[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)".

Comment: I tried but couldn't reproduce the behaviour you describe. [Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GyBNwB) is my attempt on codepen.

Comment: @mnme, I just tried, too, and jsfiddle is working fine.  I am trying to figure out what is different in my development code.  So far, I am at a loss to know what it could possibly be.

Comment: I spent a lot of time to find out that href="#" inside ny anchor tag was causing the movement.  Ugh!  At least I now know.